# Django one to one relation queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have following two models

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  age = models.SmallIntergerField()

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.OneToOneField(A)
  salary = model.IntergerField()
```

No I have got records both of them. I want to query Model A with known id and I want both A and B records.

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.age, B.salary
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
WHERE A.id=1
```

Please provide me django query (by using orm). I want to achieve this with one queryset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q = B.objects.filter(id=id).values('salary','a__id','a__name','a__age')
```

this will return a `ValuesQuerySet`

> [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)
>
> **values(*fields)** Returns a **ValuesQuerySet** — a **QuerySet** subclass that
>   returns dictionaries when used as an iterable, rather than
>   model-instance objects.
>
> Each of those dictionaries represents an object, with the keys
>   corresponding to the attribute names of model objects.

You can actually print `q.query` to get the sql query behind the `QuerySet`, which in this case is exactly as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

`result = B.objects.filter(a__id=1).values('a__id', 'a__name', 'a__age', 'salary')`

The result is a `<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet'>`, which is essentially a list of dictionaries with key as the field name and value as the actual value. If you want only the values, do this:

`result = B.objects.filter(a__id=1).values_list('a__id', 'a__name', 'a__age', 'salary')`

The result is a `<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesListQuerySet'>`, and it's essentially a list of tuples.

Comment: Ah, @zxzak is before me, but in case you want the django doc, his answer has the reference.