# Create a One to One Queryset In Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am having trouble creating a queryset by joining two one to one fields. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am trying this example here but not getting it to work. [Django one to one relation queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878137/django-one-to-one-relation-queryset)

```py
class Category_Driving (models.Model):

    ACCEPTABLE_UNACCEPTABLE = (
        ('acceptable', 'ACCEPTABLE'),
        ('unacceptable', 'UNACCEPTABLE'),
    )

    bbso_record_id =  models.OneToOneField(BBSO_Records, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    vehicle_condition = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, choices=ACCEPTABLE_UNACCEPTABLE, verbose_name="Vehicle in Safe Condition")
    seat_belt_secured = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, choices=ACCEPTABLE_UNACCEPTABLE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle_condition

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "CategoryDriving"
```

```py
class BBSO_Records(models.Model):

    severityLevel = (
        ('Level 1', 'Level 1'),
        ('Level 2', 'Level 2'),
        ('Level 3', 'Level 3'),
       )
    
    severity_level = models.CharField(max_length=7, default= "Level 3" , choices=severityLevel)
    date_recorded  = models.DateField()
    location_details = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='e.g. In the kitchen on the 4th floor.', blank=True)
```

```py
# I am trying this code in my view but it is not working. 
queryset = Category_Driving.objects.filter(id=id).values('vehicle_condition','date_recorded').\
                                annotate(record_count=Count('vehicle_condition')).order_by('vehicle_condition')
```

This is the error message I am getting:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: bbso_record_id, bbso_record_id_id, distracted, inspection, seat_belt_secured, speed, spotter, vehicle_condition

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

note: I did not show all the fields in my model in the example given. I cut them down not to show all the code.

Comment: As you have not mentioned all fields, here is my guess for your issues: while creating the model `Category_Driving`, you have assigned `primary_key=True` to some field, because of which django does not add the `id` field. But in your queryset, you are using `.filter(id=id)` and therefore django raising that `id` is not a field and provide you the possible fields choices that you can use. Error is not related to one-to-one relation, it's on the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Yadav. But I have given all fields that relates to the issue. The only reason I mentioned that I did not show all fields is because someone might have asked why is my error message showing words like "distracted, inpection", and this is because they are left off the example.

Comment: To answer your question yes I have a primary key field and it is found in the category_driving table under the field name bbso_record_id.

Comment: So instead of `.filter(id=id)` use `.filter(bbso_record_id=id)`

Comment: HI Vineet. It still does not work and i get the following error message. "TypeError at /SOS_Dashboard/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/SOS_Dashboard/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>."

Comment: Okay, try replacing `=id` with some number like `=1`, and if this resolve/change this issue, it means the issue is in how you are preparing the id variable. I cannot help you without knowing the rest of views.py code. So you have to check it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys but with some help from a user called Viking the problem was solved.          qry_unaccept_vehicle_cond = BBSO_Records.objects.filter(category_driving__vehicle_condition="unacceptable",date_recorded__range=[start_date, end_date]).values('category_driving__vehicle_condition').\
                                        annotate(record_count=Count('category_driving__vehicle_condition')).order_by('category_driving__vehicle_condition')